# Vue + Overmindjs -> Creating Interceptor for GraphQL requests

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, state

I'm using Vue with [OvermindJS](https://overmindjs.org/) (instead of Vuex) for state management. Within Overmind, I use GraphQL following [this](https://overmindjs.org/addons/graphql) tutorial from their official docs. It works like a charm, but I run into a problem with the authentication. I use a JWT approach with a refresh-cookie. That means I need to refresh the Token at certain intervals or when it's expired.

I think an interceptor that can check if the token is expired every time I make a request to my GraphQL endpoint would be the best approach. Is this possible in Overmind? Alternatively, I could create a Promise function to every created request that checks it, but I don't find that solution particularly appealing.

Cheers